# HTML/PHP page div showing margin although margin set to 0

Tags: php, html, css

I am making a site and I cannot seem to configure the layout as I would like to.

Here is what I have:

[image]

I am trying to remove the orange space along side the links on the left. I want the newsfeed section to but pushed up to the top just under the navigation bar.

The section on the left where it says 'posts by friends', 'inbox' etc. is its own div. Within that div are two more divs with smaller width, one containing the profile image and one containing the name of the user (Reece Kenney in this case). The newsfeed section is another div separate from the previous divs.

The div containing the left content has been set to have no margin so I cannot figure out why it still shows that it has a margin all the way across the page.

Here is my php code:

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'home.php')){
         echo "<div id='wrapperNoImageNewsfeedLeft'><br/> <br/>

                <div id='smallProfilePicLeft'>
                    <a href='$user' id='hyperlink'><img src='$profilePic' height='45' width='37' alt='Your profile' title='Your profile' /></a>
                </div>

                <div id='smallNameLeft'>
                    <a href='$user' id='hyperlink'>$firstName $lastName</a>
                </div>

                <br/> <br/><br/> <br/>";

            echo "<a href='home.php' id='hyperlink' style='font-weight: bold;'>Posts by Friends</a> 

            <br/> <br/>

            <a href='public_posts.php' id='hyperlink' >Posts by Public</a><br/> <br/>
            ";

        echo '<a href="/arrowBerry/my_messages.php" id="hyperlink">Inbox</a>
                </div>';
}
<div id="wrapperNoImage">
/*Newsfeed section....
...
...
*/
</div>
```

I read that I may have to 'butt' some of my content together as this problem is caused by whitespace in my code but I am unsure what this really means and which parts I would need to 'butt' together, if that is even the problem here.

UPDATE:

I was told that the php code was not needed and I need to post my html code. This is all the code I thought I needed. The only other html code on the page is for the navigation bar but I will post it anyway.

```
<div class='newsFeed'>
    <h2>Your Newsfeed:</h2>
    <a href="home.php" id="hyperlink" style='font-weight: bold;'>Posts by Friends</a>
    <a href="public_posts.php" id="hyperlink" >Posts by Public</a>
</div>


<div class="newsfeedPostForm">
    <form action="home.php" method="POST">
        <textarea id="newsfeedPost" name="post" rows="5" cols="90"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="send" class="postFormSubmit" value="Post">
    </form>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#wrapperNoImage {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: auto;
width: 780px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
border-left: 1px solid #cad3dc;
border-right: 1px solid #cad3dc;
}

#wrapperNoImageNewsfeedLeft {
height: auto;
width: 170px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
margin: none;

}
#smallProfilePicLeft {
float: left;
height: auto;
width: 50px;
margin-right: none;
}
#smallNameLeft {
float: left;
height: auto;
width: 100px;
margin-right: 0px;
}
```

UPDATE 2:
None of the solutions are working for me so I will post my whole HTML code as it appears in the browser.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>arrowBerry</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/arrowBerry/css/style.css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
        <script src="js/jquery.color.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script src="js/placeholder-js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="headerMenu">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="/arrowBerry/img/logo.png"/>
            </div>
            <div class="searchBox">
                <form action="search.php" method="GET" id="search">
                    <input type="text" name="q" size="60" placeholder="Search ..." />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <a href="/arrowBerry/home.php">Home</a>
                <a href="/arrowBerry/reece55">reece55</a>
                <a href="/arrowBerry/my_messages.php">Inbox</a>
                <a href="/arrowBerry/friend_requests.php">Friend Requests</a>
                <a href="/arrowBerry/my_pokes.php">Pokes</a>
                    <a href="/arrowBerry/accountSettings.php">Settings</a>
                <a href="/arrowBerry/logout.php">Log Out</a>
            </div>          
                </div>
    </div>
    <div id='wrapperNoImageNewsfeedLeft'><br/> <br/>
                <div id='smallProfilePicLeft'>
                    <a href='reece55' id='hyperlink'><img src='userdata/profile_pics/Od9MJ3riRbDyjo4/Screen Shot 2014-06-02 at 17.20.38.png' height='45' width='37' alt='Your profile' title='Your profile' /></a>
                </div>
                <div id='smallNameLeft'>
                    <a href='reece55' id='hyperlink'>Reece Kenney</a>
                </div>
                <br/> <br/><br/> <br/><a href='home.php' id='hyperlink' style='font-weight: bold;'>Posts by Friends</a> 
            <br/> <br/>
            <a href='public_posts.php' id='hyperlink' >Posts by Public</a><br/> <br/>
            <a href="/arrowBerry/my_messages.php" id="hyperlink">Inbox</a>
                </div>      <div id="wrapperNoImage">
        <br />
<div class='newsFeed'>
     <h2>Your Newsfeed:</h2>
     <a href="home.php" id="hyperlink" style='font-weight: bold;'>Posts by Friends</a>
     <a href="public_posts.php" id="hyperlink" >Posts by Public</a>
</div>


<div class="newsfeedPostForm">
<form action="home.php" method="POST">
<textarea id="newsfeedPost" name="post" rows="5" cols="90"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="send" class="postFormSubmit" value="Post">
</form>
</div>

<div class='bottom'>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var load = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            load++;
            $.post("friends_newsfeed_ajax.php",{load:load},function(data) {
                $('.bottom').append(data);
            })
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: We don't need the PHP. Post your HTML and CSS instead.

Comment: You're already using a DOM inspector, as proven by your screen shot. Most any decent inspector will tell you what CSS rules are being applied to the object, and where the rules are coming from. If you're getting a margin and don't want it, then use that inspector tool to figure out where the margin is being set.

Comment: Can you provide the resulting HTML and CSS? The PHP doesn't do much good here since it only produces what the browser interprets on the front end. Also, what browser(s) is this occurring in and are you having the same result in multiple browsers?

Comment: I have added the HTML and CSS. Sorry I didn't think it was needed! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out myself after a bunch or reading. I was missing the `float: left;` from the div. I was unaware that divs automatically fill up 100% width unless the user specifies using something like `float: left;`. So I simply added `float: left;` to my div in the CSS file. 
Thanks anyway everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The space you are referencing is not a margin in the strict sense of the word (if it was, it would appear as a margin when you inspect it, but your screenshot shows no margin on the selected element). If that orange box is just dead space, and you want the `#wrapperNoImage` div to display next to the `#wrapperNoImageNewsfeedLeft` div (instead of "below" it), then try setting the CSS property:

```
display: inline;
```

on both the `#wrapperNoImageNewsfeedLeft` element and the `#wrapperNoImage` element.

If this does not fix the issue, then please post a copy of the full HTML of the page as it displays in the browser. What you currently have posted might not be sufficient to thoroughly determine what is causing the line-break after the `#wrapperNoImageNewsfeedLeft` div.